# Can't Filter Items With Spaces MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I try to query for a username with a space in it, nothing is returned. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Example:

Works- 
In Compass - { username  : 'Karma' } 
In Powershell - mongo OSRS --eval "db.userstats.find({'username' : 'Karma'})"

Doesn't Work 
In Compass - { username  : "OnO Jake" } 
In Powershell - mongo OSRS --eval "db.userstats.find({'username' : 'OnO Jake'})"

After searching online it seems other examples work but not in this case, can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing special about matching spaces. Can you update your question to include the document you're trying to match?

Comment: I've found the I can search some of the names that have spaces, I guess the other have different types of spaces?

Top one below works and the other doesn't

{"_id":"5dd391299f134d7dc3971ddb","username":"Rickeh 1","userstats":[["Overall","51129","2056","193920247"]"date":"Tue Nov 19 2019 06:52:25 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}

{"_id":"5dd0974d8c32d2fb8c3d046e","username":"OnO Jake","userstats":[["Overall","20539","2174","869390262"]"date":"Sun Nov 17 2019 00:41:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}

Comment: There are non regular space characters between some users. Users only have 1-9a-Z so this strips out every character they are not.

$Username = $Username -replace "[^A-Za-z0-9]", ' '

Can now find the ono jake document when inserted using this method